# DrawImage doesn't show CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an `img` to a `canvas`. However, styles aren't carrying over, whether I set the `style` attribute or do it in the CSS.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TastesLikeTurkey/9nphztzp/16/) showing what I'm trying to do.

I've also tried applying the styles to the `canvas` itself. This displays correctly, but when I perform `canvas.toDataURL(...)` it doesn't get the styles.

Is there some other way to apply styles to the generated data?

Comment: That will depend on what styles you want to apply. CSS width and height easy, CSS filters, 3D transforms a lot of hard work

Comment: @Blindman67 Filters is what I'm going for, just like in the fiddle. I don't care about 3D transforms.

Comment: From [this deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42095361/) I'll quote a comment by [K3N](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n): "You can use the new [filter property](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/filter) on the context itself. Use the same CSS filters there and it will be applied to the image data itself. Make sure the image is loaded fulfilling CORS otherwise extraction will fail. In older browsers or browsers without support you will need to mimic those filters. The CSS filter specifications have the receipts for the various filters."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply filters to your canvas content, you can use the cutting-edge [`filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter), which uses the same syntax the CSS `filter` property. Before you draw your image, do

```
context.filter = "grayscale(1)";
```

And you can reset it for anything else you do in the future by

```
 context.filter = "none";
```

Your filtered image will remain correctly filtered -- the `filter` property basically tells the canvas context, "Whatever I draw from now on should have this filter applied," so changes only affect future drawing operations.

Comment: Thanks! I still think it would be nicer for CSS styles to automatically apply, but fortunately this does exactly what I'm wanting in this particular case.

Comment: Filter support is limited. Check browser compatibility if you intend to roll out these types of features.